# Move turtle slightly closer to random coordinate on each update

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm doing a homework and I want to know how can I move turtle to a random location a small step each time. Like can I use turtle.goto() in a slow motion?

Someone said I should use `turtle.setheading()` and `turtle.forward()` but I'm confused on how to use `setheading()` when the destination is random.

I'm hoping the turtle could move half radius (which is 3.5) each time I update the program to that random spot.

Comment: So, if you are using turtle, somewhere in your program you should have a line which reads `import turtle`.  This adds the Turtle module to your Python program.  The documentation for all the standard library modules (and much more) is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html).  There's a module called random, and you can use its functions if you `import random`.  The documentation for random is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html).

Comment: Thanks and I've already imported that two when I've started  my homework. I just really need to know is there a 'moving small steps each time I update version' of turtle.goto().

Comment: How new are you to programming?  I know I have to teach my beginning students that functions aren't just commands, they can also return results.  Variable names help you to hold on to a result for multiple lines of your program.  If whole numbers of degrees are enough directions for you, then `x = random.randint(0,359)` is a statement which calls a function which returns a random integer between 0 and 359 and puts it in a variable named x.  `turtle.setheading(x)` can accept a variable x as an argument, an angle in degrees, just as easily as it accepts a constant like 30 or 90.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the term *half radius* twice in your question's title and text, but never really explain it.  For purposes of your question, we're just talking about some arbitrary small distance -- correct?

I would avoid `import time` and `time.sleep()` as they work against an event-driven world like turtle.  Instead, I would use turtle's own `ontimer()` method to keep things in synch:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randrange

HALF_RADIUS = 3.5  # unexplained constant
DELAY = 1000  # milliseconds
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 640, 480
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def forward_slowly(distance):
    if distance > 0:
        turtle.forward(min(distance, HALF_RADIUS))

        remaining = max(distance - HALF_RADIUS, 0)

        screen.ontimer(lambda d=remaining: forward_slowly(d), DELAY)
    else:
        screen.ontimer(move_target, DELAY)

def move_target():
    x = randrange(CURSOR_SIZE - WIDTH//2, WIDTH//2 - CURSOR_SIZE)
    y = randrange(CURSOR_SIZE - HEIGHT//2, HEIGHT//2 - CURSOR_SIZE)
    target.goto(x, y)

    target.pendown()

    turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(target))

    forward_slowly(turtle.distance(target))

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)

turtle = Turtle('turtle')
turtle.speed('slowest')
turtle.width(3)

target = Turtle('turtle')
target.speed('fastest')
target.color('red')
target.penup()

move_target()

screen.exitonclick()
```

(Any resemblence to a Pepé Le Pew cartoon is purely coincidental.)

Comment: Thxx a lot I've been stuck on this for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to move a small step, stop, and repeat? If so, you can ‘import time’ and add ‘time.sleep(0.1)’ after each ‘forward’